# How to set Alias name in Mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

For reducing the MongoDB's document size in mongoose, I want to use the alias feature. But I don't know how to set that for  **location**?

```
const questionSchema = new Schema({
    location: {
        country:  { type: String },
        province: { type: String },
        town:     { type: String },
    });
```

```
const questionSchema = new Schema({
    l: { //alias: 'location', <--  **HOW CAN I SET ALIAS FOR LOCATION ???**
        c: { type: String, alias: 'country'  },
        p: { type: String, alias: 'province' },
        t: { type: String, alias: 'town'     },
    });
```

Comment: you can defined separate schema of location after use in question schema

Answer (score 0):

We can define location schema separately after using them.

```
const locationSchema = new Schema({
        country:  { type: String },
        province: { type: String },
        town:     { type: String },
    });

const questionSchema = new Schema({location:locationSchema});
```

Comment: I edited the question. how can I set an alias for "location" for this solution?

Comment: in this case `new Schema({l:locationSchema})` , how can I set **"location"** as alias for `l` object ?

Answer (score 0):

try to this shape the

```
 const LocationSchema = new Schema({
        location: {
            country:  { type: String },

            //what it is content attribute withe type 

        }});
    const questionSchema = new Schema({
    location:LocationSchema 
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const locationSchema = new Schema({
  country: {
    type: String
  },
  province: {
    type: String
  },
  town: {
    type: String
  },
});

const questionSchema = new Schema({
  l: {
    type: locationSchema,
    alias: 'location'
  }
});
```

I am guessing this should work for you.